# Asynchronous programming in Objective-C: I feel like there is repetitive code here and I don't know what I can do about it

Tags: ios, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

I have been working with async programming for a while now and I think I understand the concepts, but there is a certain scenario I feel like I am not getting.  Check out the code:

```
-(void)someMethod:completionHandler:(void (^)(int result))handler
{
    [anotherObject asyncMethod1Success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
    {
        if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString1])
        {
            // some code

            if (handler)
            {
                handler(1);
            }
        }
        else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString2])
        {
            // some different code

            if (handler)
            {
                handler(1);
            }
        }
        else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString3])
        {
            // even different code

            [anotherObject asyncMethod2Success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
            {
                if (handler)
                {
                    handler(1);
                }
            }
            failure:^(NSError *error)
            {
                if (handler)
                {
                    handler(2);
                }
            }];
        }
    }
    failure:^(NSError *error)
    {
        if (handler)
        {
            handler(2);
        }
    }];
}
```

Basically, handler needs to get called once there is either an error or both async operations return successfully.  I feel like there is repetitive code here and I don't know what I can do about it.  I can't call handler() unconditionally in asyncMethod1's success block because case #3 needs it's async method to succeed or fail for it to be called.

Can anyone suggest a pattern to help here?  I feel the most uncomfortable when working with nested async operations like this one.

Comment: Can't you declare the failure/success block once before calling the method and then pass its reference to the function?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I am not sure how this helps.  If I understand you correctly, you are talking about moving the success and failure methods into separate methods, which will make the code look better, but I'm not sure how that will solve the repetitive code issue, if there is a solution.

Comment: is "someKey" the same key every time?

Comment: Yes, the key is the same every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest change I made was to define a block variable that took care of the multiple checks for whether or not `handler` existed.  To alleviate your uneasiness with nested asynchronous methods I just defined a new method and called it.  The rest of the changes are just formatting.  In the end, I think this still provides the same functionality and is a little more compact and easier to follow.

I wasn't sure if `asyncMethod1` and `2` were objects or not, so I just assumed they are methods defined within the same class and inserted `self`.

```
- (void)callAsyncMethod2WithHandler:(void (^)(int result))handler {
    [self asyncMethod2Success:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        handler(1);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        handler(2);
    }];
}

- (void)someMethod:(void (^)(int result))handler {
    void (^safeHandler)(int) = ^void (int theResult) {
        if (handler) handler(theResult);
    };

    [self asyncMethod1Success:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        NSString *someValue = dict[@"someKey"];
        if ([someValue isEqualToString:kString1]) {
            // some code
            safeHandler(1);
        } else if ([someValue isEqualToString:kString2]) {
            safeHandler(1);
        } else if ([someValue isEqualToString:kString3]) {
            [self callAsyncMethod2WithHandler:safeHandler];
        }
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        safeHandler(2);
    }];
}
```

Comment: The async methods do exist in another object.  I lost that detail when I took my original code and simplified it.  I will update the code.

Comment: Since this is a subjective kind of question, in my mind, I have to pick the answer I like the best and I have to go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but it's a reformatting of your code to make it a little simpler.  It may not work (depending on what the `//some code` is).  First what I see in your code is that it does nothing if the handler is not valid (this is where the `//some code` changes my response.  If you put a return into the only if/then case where you do not call `handler(1)` then you can call it at the end of the function.

```
-(void)someMethod:completionHandler:(void (^)(int result))handler
{
    if(handler)
    {
        [asyncMethod1 success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
        {
            NSString *test = dict[@"someKey"];
            if (test isEqualToString:kString1])
            {
                // some code
            }
            else if (test isEqualToString:kString2])
            {

            }
            else if (test isEqualToString:kString3])
            {
                [asyncMethod2 success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
                 {
                    handler(1);
                }
                failure:^(NSError *error)
                {
                    handler(2);
                }];
                return;
            }
            handler(1);
        }
        failure:^(NSError *error)
        {
            handler(2);
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: In your version, asyncMethod1 and asyncMethod2 aren't called if `handler` is nil.  That differs from the original behavior of the code.  Maybe that's ok for the OP, but its not quite the same behavior.

Comment: @Jonathan I did mention that in my post.  My simplification would only be valid is `//some code` is not important to the rest of the program.

Comment: I saw your post.  That's not my point.  Your simplification may **also** not be valid if calling `asyncMethod1` and/or `asyncMethod2` when `handler` is nil is important to the rest of the program.

Comment: Calling the async methods is a must.  It doesn't matter if handler is nil or not, at least one of them must be called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a contrived example, but if you don't mind to utilize a small third party library, your code can be mimicked as follows:

```
handler_block_t handler = ...;

RXPromise* p0 = someMethod();

p0.then(^id(id dict) {
    if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString1]) {
        // some code
        return @"OK";
    }
    else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString2]) {
        return @"OK";
    }
    else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString3]) {
        return asyncMethod2();
    } else {
        return nil; // not handled
    }
}, nil).then(^id(id result /* dict or @"OK" or nil */) {
    // parameter result is either @"OK", nil (not handled), or asyncMethod2's eventual result value:
    if (result != nil) {
        handler(1);
    }
    return nil;
}, ^id(NSError* error) {
    handler(2);
    return nil;
});
```

Of course, if you would utilize Promises (there are a few libraries in Objective-C which implement it) , you likely would restructure the code in order to become more comprehensible.

I'm the author of [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise), which is an Objective-C library which implements the concept of Promises according the [Promises/A+ Specification](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec).

Comment: I certainly appreciate your answer, but I am trying to see if I can eliminate the repetitive code while using the stock Objective-C first.

Comment: @user2370215 That's fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Here's an example that's closer to your original code, maybe you like this arrangement?

```
enum CompletionResult { Fail, Success };

@interface Test : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) dispatch_queue_t q ;
@end

@implementation Test

-(dispatch_queue_t)q
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue() ;
}

-(void)method1WithSuccessBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary * dict))successBlock failureBlock:(void(^)(void))failBlock
{
    // long running method 1
    // return YES/NO on success/failure
}

-(void)method2WithSuccessBlock:(void(^)(NSDictionary * dict))successBlock failureBlock:(void(^)(void))failBlock
{
    // long running method 2
    // return YES/NO on success/failure
}

-(void)test:(void(^)(enum CompletionResult))block
{
    __block BOOL performAsync2 = NO ;
    void (^successBlock)(NSDictionary * dict) = ^(NSDictionary * dict){
        NSString * value = dict[@"someKey"] ;
        if ( [ value isEqualToString:A ] )
        {

        }
        else if ( [ value isEqualToString:B ])
        {

        }
        else if ( [ value isEqualToString:C ] )
        {
            performAsync2 = YES ;
        }

        if (  !performAsync2 && block )
        {
            block( Success ) ;
        }

    };
    void (^failBlock)() = ^{
        if ( block ) { block( Fail ) ; }
    };

    dispatch_sync( self.q, ^{ [ self method1WithSuccessBlock:successBlock failureBlock:failBlock ] } ) ;
    if ( performAsync2 )
    {
        dispatch_sync( self.q, ^{ [ self method2WithSuccessBlock:successBlock failureBlock:failBlock ] } ) ;
    }
}

@end
```

---

Could you do something like this?

```
@interface Test : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) dispatch_queue_t q ;
@end
@implementation Test

-(dispatch_queue_t)q
{
    return dispatch_get_main_queue() ;
}
-(BOOL)method1
{
    // long running method 1
    // return YES/NO on success/failure
}

-(BOOL)method2
{
    // long running method 2
    // return YES/NO on success/failure
}

-(void)test:(void(^)(enum CompletionResult))block
{
    __block BOOL didSucceed = NO ;
    dispatch_sync( self.q, ^{ didSucceed = [ self method1 ] ; }) ;
    if ( !didSucceed )
    {
        if ( block ) { block( Fail ) ; }
        return ;
    }
    dispatch_sync( self.q, ^{ didSucceed = [ self method2 ] ; }) ;
    if ( !didSucceed )
    {
        if ( block ) { block( Fail ) ; }
        return ;
    }

    if ( block ) { block( Success ) ; }
}

@end
```

You'd have to change how you call async1 and async2... but the main code is simple to follow. Make sure the queue you use runs in the background of course.

Answer (score 0):

How about using blocks?

```
-(void)someMethod:completionHandler:(void (^)(int result))handler
{
    void (^safeHandler)(int) = ^(int value) {
        if (handler)
        {
            handler(value);
        }
    };

    [anotherObject asyncMethod1Success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
    {
        if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString1])
        {
            // some code

            safeHandler(1);
        }
        else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString2])
        {
            // some different code

            safeHandler(1);
        }
        else if ([dict[@"someKey"] isEqualToString:kString3])
        {
            // even different code

            [anotherObject asyncMethod2Success:^(NSDictionary *dict)
            {
                safeHandler(1);
            }
            failure:^(NSError *error)
            {
                safeHandler(2);
            }];
        }
    }
    failure:^(NSError *error)
    {
        safeHandler(2);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your repetitive example is not only related to asynchronous aspect of that method. I would focus on removing duplicates from `if-else` branches, too.

#### Tips to reduce the code:

- **Don't create methods taking success and failure block.** Use one block to report both cases. (Yes, sometimes you can't just change existing methods.)
- **Check for block being `nil` only once** and use some default empty block in that case.
- **Extract code that is common** to all `if-else` branches outside of them.
- **If possible, avoid doing `if-else` at all.** Sometimes it's easier to use some kind of mapping with `NSDictionary` or other approach.

Here is the code with applied tips:

```
- (void)someMethodWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(int result))handler {

    if ( ! handler) handler = ^(int result) {}; // Use empty block, so it's never nil.

    [anotherObject asyncMethod1Success:^(NSDictionary *dict) {

        NSString *someString = dict[@"someKey"];
        int result = 0; // Default

        if ([someString isEqualToString:kString1]) {
            // some code
            result = 1;
        }
        else if ([someString isEqualToString:kString2]) {
            // some different code
            result = 1;
        }
        // ... maybe even more branches
        else if ([someString isEqualToString:kString3]) {
            // even different code

            [anotherObject asyncMethod2Success:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
                handler(1);
            }
            failure:^(NSError *error) {
                handler(2);
            }];
        }

        if (result) handler(result);
    }
    failure:^(NSError *error) {
        handler(2);
    }];
}
```

I'm not sure how many result codes do you have. If you only indicates success/failure, there may be easier approach.